# Regarding good performance of Android AOSP music player Albums list

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

The Albums list in the Music Browser Activity of `AOSP music player` loads the album arts very smoothly and does not block the scrolling as if the images were loaded `asynchronously`. However, I looked through the codes and found nothing in it that is asynchronous. It does not use AsyncTask or a background thread.

If anybody has had experience with the app and its codes, could you please shine a light on how this very desirable effect could be achieved?

I'm building a Music player app and I have implemented a `background thread` that handles the `Bitmap` processing but I still have to do the bitmap drawing on the UI thread. The scrolling performance is slightly better than without the background thread, but it is still not perfectly smooth. I guess it can be improved by resizing and reducing the quality of the album art bitmaps before drawing on the ui.

Even so, the album art loading behaviour in the AOSP music app seems to be the best. The images of the `list` items that are off screen also seem to be always removed from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the same effect by following [This](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html).